# Replace tooltip RGB values with their color names

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

How to change the following?
To where the tooltips show **color names** instead of the generated **RGB numerals**.

```
<div class="sp-palette-container">
    <div class="sp-palette sp-thumb sp-cf">
        <div class="sp-cf sp-palette-row sp-palette-row-0">
            <span class="sp-thumb-el sp-thumb-dark" data-color="rgb(12, 14, 16)" title="rgb(12, 14, 16)">
                <span class="sp-thumb-inner" style="background-color:rgb(12, 14, 16);"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="sp-thumb-el sp-thumb-light" data-color="rgb(231, 234, 238)" title="rgb(231, 234, 238)">
            <span class="sp-thumb-inner" style="background-color:rgb(231, 234, 238);"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="sp-thumb-el sp-thumb-dark" data-color="rgb(104, 106, 109)" title="rgb(104, 106, 109)">
            <span class="sp-thumb-inner" style="background-color:rgb(104, 106, 109);"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="sp-thumb-el sp-thumb-dark sp-thumb-active" data-color="rgb(208, 14, 0)" title="rgb(208, 14, 0)">
            <span class="sp-thumb-inner" style="background-color:rgb(208, 14, 0);"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="sp-thumb-el sp-thumb-light" data-color="rgb(255, 171, 0)" title="rgb(255, 171, 0)">
            <span class="sp-thumb-inner" style="background-color:rgb(255, 171, 0);"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="sp-thumb-el sp-thumb-dark" data-color="rgb(119, 94, 160)" title="rgb(119, 94, 160)">
            <span class="sp-thumb-inner" style="background-color:rgb(119, 94, 160);"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    <div class="sp-cf sp-palette-row sp-palette-row-selection"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: None of the colors in your question have common names in css or svg.

Comment: Hi and welcome to [so]. Please, check the small guide [ask] and take the [welcoming tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the possible rgb strings (and there anren't that many of them) you could do something like:

```
var rgbToColorNames = {
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)": "Red",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)": "Green",
    ...
}

var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("sp-thumb-el");
for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var span = spans[i];
    span.title = rgbToColorNames[span.title];
}
```

Otherwise there's no way to convert rgb values back to English. So if the rgb values can be anything, you are kind of out of luck. Maybe you could use math to group ranges of rgb values together to represent one color.

Comment: Would this work in the custom.css file (woocommerce)?